# How to save a Python 2 idle/shell/command prompt interactive session on Windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, history, python-idle

I run calculations on Windows for hours and would like to have the calculation report/log inside the interactive IDLE/shell window be saved to a file at the end by a command.
Would be nice to exit() and close the window too.
As much as I like Linux, this is an Unattended Windows machine, hence, some modules/commands are not available, sadly, and the ability to install other software is limited. 
The fact that the developers did not think of a command to save the transactions within the IDLE/shell is surprising.

I know in some environments you can direct the output of a job, like a report to another text file by using the key -o, --o, --output, > to a text file. Surprisingly Python does not support anything like that!

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Command Prompt supports stdout redirection and probably stderr redirection. I just tested `python -c "print(test)" > F:/dev/tem/out.txt` and the print out went to out.txt. Replace -c "print('test') with script.py and the same should happen. Piping stdout of one program to stdin of another might work. You might be able to chain programs with a .bat file. PowerShell likely is more powerful and flexible, but I have never used it.

I am not completely clear on what you are asking, but I hope the following answers your questions.

Python runs in 2 modes: batch and interactive.  Interactive mode is intended for ephermeral interaction with a human.  Batch mode is for unattended computation, with occasional screen messages, but with most results sent to a file other than the screen.  Both modes are combined when you run `python -i xyz.py`.  The file is first run in batch mode, and then Python shifts to interactive mode.

It sounds like you should be using batch mode rather than either Python's or IDLE's interactive mode.  If your code runs from IDLE, you should be able to run it directly with  the same python.exe that you used to run IDLE.  There are exceptions, of course, if one makes one's code dependent on running within IDLE, but this is unlikely to be an accident or to be needed for unattended running.

The IDLE Shell simulates interactive Python.  When a file is run from an editor window, IDLE simulates `python -i file-being-edited.py`, with screen output going to Shell.  In either case, an interactive user can save the contents of Shell with the File => Save As menu command.  So there *is* such a command.  There are also close window and exit commands and shortcuts.

In IDLE's intended use, as an interactive python learning and program development environment, there is no need from for a program to issue these commands.  To save data in a file, a program can open a file and write data directly.

Comment: Thank you. No matter how I fire the command, shell/IDLE/Command line, there are valuable calculations not saved at the end. I save it manually but these are unattended calculations and the module is provided by a private entity. I would like to have further chain calculations without having to go over and save them manually or losing them due to a hardware failure,... I know in some environments you can direct the output of a job, like a report to another text file by using the key -o, --o, --output, > to a text file. Surprisingly Python does not support anything like that!

Comment: Windows Command Prompt supports stdout redirection and probably stderr redirection.  I just tested `python -c "print(test)" > F:/dev/tem/out.txt` and the print out went to out.txt.  Replace `-c "print('test')` with `script.py` and the same should happen.  Piping stdout of one program to stdin of another might work.  You might be able to chain programs with a .bat file.  PowerShell likely is more powerful and flexible, but I have never used it.

Comment: Hey Terry, I don't know why that didn't come to my mind! You can see from my comment that I knew it was possible but never tried! Anyhow, I changed the question to make it more relatable and edited your answer in and accepted it as the right answer as it does the trick. I know how to take it from there. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you can install Jupyter Notebook (not separate software, but just a python module)

```
pip install jupyter
```

Jupyter notebook is highly helpful for saving and sharing your code. It can be used as both a shell and as a script editor.

Comment: Thank you. IPython is installed. The code does not work inside Jupyter but works fine when called from IDLE/shell. Could be incompatibilities? Preferably, it would be great to have a command within python to save these calculations for further chain calculations with in the same script. Thanks